# How can I compare two tables in PHP and display not matched software name from table 1?

Tags: php, mysql

[image: This is Table 1]

```
 This is Table1
```

[image: This is Table 2]

```
 This is Table2
```

I want to compare table2 to table1 and display software name from table 1 which is not present in table2.

Comment: I am trying to display software name from Table1 which is not entry in Table2.

Comment: please show your SQL query?

Comment: which is foreign key field in table1 ?

Comment: You can do a loop to put each of the softwarename's from table2 into a variable, and then do something like ```$result = mysql_query("SELECT software FROM table1 WHERE software= '$softwareFromTable2'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
     // row not found
}```

Comment: You don't appear to be *trying* at all. That's not how SO works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to use sql query to serve your purpose. Integrate the query into your php script to get the report.

master1

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
|  2 | B    |
|  3 | C    |
|  4 | D    |
|  5 | E    |
|  6 | F    |
+----+------+
```

slave1

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+
| id | name1 | name2 | name3 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | A     | C     | B     |
|  2 | B     | D     | G     |
|  3 | O     | A     | D     |
|  4 | E     | F     | M     |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Here is your solution

```
SELECT slave1.id, slave1.name1 AS name FROM slave1 LEFT JOIN master1 AS m1 ON slave1.name1 = m1.name WHERE m1.name IS NULL
UNION
SELECT slave1.id, slave1.name2 AS name FROM slave1 LEFT JOIN master1 AS m2 ON slave1.name2 = m2.name WHERE m2.name IS NULL
UNION
SELECT slave1.id, slave1.name3 AS name FROM slave1 LEFT JOIN master1 AS m3 ON slave1.name3 = m3.name WHERE m3.name IS NULL

+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  3 | O    |
|  2 | G    |
|  4 | M    |
+----+------+
```

Thanks

Comment: If name is n number of in slave1 then how can we take in loop using php?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare two tables, here are some tutorials

1. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/compare-two-tables-to-find-unmatched-records-mysql.aspx
2. [Compare two table and find matching columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066124/compare-two-table-and-find-matching-columns)

Answer (score 0):

```
  This is Table2

 <?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "audit");

 // Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$softwarename = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['softwarename']);
// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO licence (softwarename) VALUES ('$softwarename')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);

?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 this is Table1

<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("audit", $link);
//$name = $_POST['name'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM report";
$res = mysql_query($sql,$link);
$softwares = array();
$count = 0;
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $softwares[] = $result;
}

echo "<table border=1>";

echo "<th>IP address</th>";
echo "<th>MAC address</th>";
echo "<th>Software</th>";
echo "<th>Version</th>";

foreach ($softwares as $sw) {
    $cols = count($sw);
   // echo $sw['ipaddress']."<br>";
    //echo $sw['macaddress']."<br>";

    //echo $cols;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $cols; $i++) {

        if (!empty($sw['software'.$i])) {
            echo "<tr>";           
            echo "<td>".$sw['ipaddress']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$sw['macaddress']."</td>";

            echo "<td>".$sw['software'.$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$sw['version'.$i]."</td>";

            echo "</tr>";

            $count = $count+1;

        }

    }
}
echo $count;
echo "</table>";

?>
```